# First order logic augmented with (Prolog) cut?

Tags: logic, computer-science

Prolog is a programming language rooted in a "procedural" interpretation of Horn clauses, whereby a goal (sentence) may be proved by searching a tree of possible proofs constructed from the horn clauses in the program. The language includes a 0-ary logical connective "cut," which "prunes" branches from the search tree. I have always seen the semantics of `!` defined in terms of the proof search algorithm, and never in terms of first order logic. [Some discussion on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983019/is-it-possible-to-express-prologs-cut-in-first-order-logic/73991192#73991192) suggests that there isn't really a natural way to model `!` in first order logic.

I would like to construct a mathematical logic that can be used for a denotational semantics of "Pure Prolog" with cut, but I'm not sure what its axioms would be. To make this a bit more precise, suppose all Prolog terms are of one of the forms that follows, and that any Prolog term $\texttt{p}$ has a denotation $[[\texttt{p}]]$.

Denotations for propositions:
$$ [[\texttt{p :- q.}]] = [[\texttt{q}]] \rightarrow [[\texttt{p}]] $$
$$ [[\texttt{p, q}]] = [[\texttt{p}]] \wedge [[\texttt{q}]] $$
$$ [[\texttt{p; q}]] = [[\texttt{p}]] \vee [[\texttt{q}]] $$
$$ [[\texttt{!}]] = ! $$

A variable $\texttt{X}$ introduced in the head of a rule (left side of $\texttt{:-}$, right side of an implication) is universally quantified, and may occur free in $\texttt{q}$:
$$ [[\texttt{p(..., X, ...) :- q}]] = \forall X, [[\texttt{q}]] \rightarrow p(..., X, ...) $$

Variables introduced in the body of a rule (right side of $\texttt{:-}$, left side of an implication) are existentially quantified:
$$ [[\texttt{p :- q(..., X, ...)}]] = \exists X, [[\texttt{q(..., X, ...)}]] \rightarrow p $$

If every Prolog program and goal succeeds if and only if its denotation is satisfiable in the logic, what axioms are admissible? For example, $P \wedge Q \vdash Q \wedge P$ is definitely not a tautology, but I think $P \wedge Q \vdash P$ is.

Comment: Not an answer but a comment : I have been surprized to discover recently that *linear logic* also has a cut operator: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/cutlin94.pdf

Comment: I only briefly skimmed the linked paper, but that seems to be talking about the rule of inference from sequent calculus (c.f. cut elimination theorem) than the Prolog connective that happens to share the name "cut." Does that seem right?